# problema con función que recibe como parámetro varios arrays

Tags: javascript

Una librería tiene una función que permite recibir varios arrays pero no sé cómo insertarlos.

> ejemplo 1
>
> ```
> funcion([1.3,  1.7,  0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 0.4]);
> ```
>
> ejemplo 2
>
> ```
> funcion([1.3,  1.7,  0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 0.4],
>         [21.3,  41.7, 30.5, 1.5, 2.5,.4]);
> ```
>
> ejemplo 3
>
> ```
> funcion([1.3,  1.7,  0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 0.4],
>         [1.8,  1.8,  0.58, 0.25, 1.25, 0.44],
>         [12.3,  11.7,  10.5, 10.5, 12.5, 4.4]);
> ```

¿Cómo podría insertar esa clase de parámetros dinámicos?

Lo estoy haciendo con un `for` e insertando cada array por solitario, pero lo quiero insertar todos juntos.

Mi código es este:

```
for (var i = 0; i < retorno.length; i++) {
    console.log(maquina.funcion(retorno[i]));
};
```

El contenido del siguiente `array` de `arrays` debo insertar a la función de la librería:

```
[[-220,-140,-100,-290,230,-400],[-440,0,0,200,-230,100],[-22‌​0,150,-230,-90,0,-19‌​0 ],[1140,0,230,410,-100,300] [ [ 1140, 0, 230, 410, -100, 300 ], [ -220, 150, -230, -90, 0, -190 ], [ -440, 0, 0, 200, -230, 100 ], [ -220, -140, -100, -290, 230, -400 ] ]]
```

Answer (score 4):

### 1. Parámetros dinámicos

Para recibir ***parámetros dinámicos***, se puede utilizar el [Objeto arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/arguments).

> El objeto `arguments` es una variable local disponible dentro de todas las funciones.
>
> Este objeto contiene una entrada para cada argumento pasado a la función, la primera entrada tiene un índice de 0.

```js
function parametrosDinamicos() {
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        console.log("Parámetro " + i + ":", arguments[i]);
    }
}

parametrosDinamicos( ['primer', 'parám.'], 
                     {'otro': 'más'}, 
                     ['tercer', 'parámetro', 'pasado']
                    );
```

---

Desde [ES2015](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Novedades_en_JavaScript/ECMAScript_6_support_in_Mozilla), existe el [Operador de propagación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Spread_operator), una de las nuevas características *interesantes*.

> El operador de propagación ***spread operator*** permite que una expresión sea expandida en situaciones donde se esperan múltiples argumentos (llamadas a funciones) o múltiples elementos (arrays literales).

<sup>* Vale la pena leer los diferentes usos descriptos en [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Spread_operator).</sup>

```js
function parametrosDinamicos(...paramIterable) {
    let i = 0;
    paramIterable.forEach(param => {
        console.log("Parámetro " + i++ + ":", param);
    });
}

parametrosDinamicos( ['primer', 'parám.'], 
                     {'otro': 'más'}, 
                     ['tercer', 'parámetro', 'pasado']
                    );
```

---

### 2. Un único parámetro como array

Alternativamente, en vez de usar *parámetros dinámicos*, se puede simplificar el caso pasando un **array de 2 dimensiones** (con cada array dentro de un único parámetro que es un array).

```js
function miFuncion(arrayDeArrays) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayDeArrays.length; i++) {
        console.log("Array " + i + ":", arrayDeArrays[i]);
    }
}

miFuncion( [
             ['primer', 'índice'], 
             ['otro', 'array'], 
             ['tercer', 'array', 'pasado']
           ]
         );
```

---

### 3. Un array como diferentes parámetros

Por último, para el caso contrario, si se tiene un array, pero se quiere pasar cada elemento del array como un parámetro diferente a una función, se utiliza [Function.prototype.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Function/apply).

```js
function prueba(a, b){
    console.log("A:", a);
    console.log("B:", b);
}

parametros = [[2,3],[4,5]];
prueba.apply(this,parametros)
```

O, desde [ES2015](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Novedades_en_JavaScript/ECMAScript_6_support_in_Mozilla), con el [operador de propagación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Spread_operator):

```js
function prueba(a, b){
    console.log("A:", a);
    console.log("B:", b);
}

parametros = [[2,3],[4,5]];
prueba(...parametros)
```

Comment: lo que pasa es que yo tengo un simple array [1,2,3,4] y no se como ponerlo aca `parametrosDinamicos( ['primer', 'parám.'], 
                     {'otro': 'más'}, 
                     ['tercer', 'parámetro', 'pasado']
                    );`

Comment: solo fue un ejemplo [1,2,3,4] ahora con array real me devuelve `Parámetro 0: [ [ 790, 0, 80, 170, 40, 90 ],
  [ -20, 140, -100, 50, -50, 60 ],
  [ -640, 0, -50, -50, -100, -40 ],
  [ -20, -130, 40, -80, 80, -160 ] ]` el primer corchete esta demas

Comment: @rn3w Eso significa que estás pasando un array de 2 dimensiones como primer y único parámetro... No es lo mismo `funcion([1,2,3], [4, 5])` que `funcion([ [123], [4, 5] ])`

Comment: en realidad este es mi array `[[-220,-140,-100,-290,230,-400],[-440,0,0,200,-230,100],[-220,150,-230,-90,0,-190
],[1140,0,230,410,-100,300]
[ [ 1140, 0, 230, 410, -100, 300 ],
  [ -220, 150, -230, -90, 0, -190 ],
  [ -440, 0, 0, 200, -230, 100 ],
  [ -220, -140, -100, -290, 230, -400 ] ]]` disculpa no es de 2 dimensiones

Comment: es un array que contiene arrays, esos arrays tengo que pasarlo a la funcion

Comment: @rn3w Entonces sería el tercer caso que publiqué, que llama a `console.log()`, pero podría ser cualquier función con cada índice del array... Si hay algo que no estoy entendiendo, te diría que edites la pregunta con un caso concreto y el resultado esperado.

Comment: esa funcion de la libreria permite insertar varios arrays, lo que quiero hacer es insertar todo el contenido del array de arrays en una llamada